# Submitting form set all null inputs and their associated hidden input fields to disabled

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

I have a form with multiple input fields where users may choose to enter a value or not. Next to each input field is a hidden input field that will send a specific id unique to the previous input field.  On form submission, all blank input fields are disabled.  This I got to work using this code.

```
function disableEmptyInputs(form) {
    var controls = form.elements;
    for (var i = 0, iLen = controls.length; i < iLen; i++) {
        controls[i].disabled = controls[i].value == '';
    }
}
```

I now want to also disable the hidden inputs if their primary visible input field is null

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="input-group mb-3">
<div class="input-group-prepend">
<span class="input-group-text">$</span>
</div>
<input name="Pay" placeholder="Amount for A" class="form-control" type="text" />
<input type="hidden" name="PayId" value="A" />
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="input-group mb-3">
<div class="input-group-prepend">
<span class="input-group-text">$</span>
</div>
<input name="Pay" placeholder="Amount for B" class="form-control" type="text" />
<input type="hidden" name="PayId" value="B" />
</div>
</div>
```

Any help will be really appreciated. The form submits to a c# backend where I am able to filter out all blanks If I allowed all blanks to be submitted but I felt if I could filter all blanks by making them disabled at the client side in addition to server side that will be better.

Comment: Hi, can you use jquery ?

Comment: Yes I can use jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.each` loop to iterate through your form elements and then compare if the value of input is `""` simply disable that input and also the input next to it using `.next()`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$("form").on("submit", function() {
  //loop through input(exclude hidden input)..select..etc
  $("form").find("input:not(:hidden),select").each(function() {
    //if the value is empty
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
      $(this).prop("disabled", true) //disable
      $(this).next().prop("disabled", true) //also next field (hidden) disable
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
      </div>
      <input name="Pay" placeholder="Amount for A" class="form-control" type="text" value="abc" />
      <input type="hidden" name="PayId" value="A" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
      </div>
      <input name="Pay" placeholder="Amount for B" class="form-control" type="text" />
      <input type="hidden" name="PayId" value="B" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <button>Click me ..</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks very much can this be called on form submit? which I can call from the form tag like onsubmit = "disableEmptyInputs(this)"  I am using a form wizard with validation that presents the submit input as the last step.

Comment: it disables the input empty field alright but not the hidden input field that has a value I just realised not sure what is causing that

Comment: hidden input is  next to original input or not ?

Comment: On form submit the function does not run  at all. I am using jquery-steps with validation. I am not sure why

Comment: yes just as I gave, hidden input is next  to original input  and  each pair share a common div with class input-group

Comment: Hi, how about [this](https://jsfiddle.net/9Lemwj21/) way ?